# Spring Transaction Annotations - Execute on Success

Tags: spring, transactions

I'm using Spring application events within my service layer to notify the wider system when specific events occur. The issue I have is that the events are fired within a transactional context (I'm using Spring's `@Transactional` annotation). The danger is that I fire an event and then the transaction fails on commit (can happen when using, for example, Hibernate). In this scenario, the event listeners will be assuming some state that will then be rolled back after they've executed. The danger here is that I may, for example, have sent an email to confirm a user's registration on a website when, in fact, their user account was not actually created.

Is there a way, preserving the use of annotations, to somewhere flag an event to be fired after the transaction commits? It kind of seems somewhat analogous to using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable runnable)` when doing GUI programming in Java Swing. I want to say, execute this bit of code later on once the current transaction commits successfully.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: This is all handled natively in Spring now via annotations.

See https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2 specifically the section about the new @TransactionalEventListener annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to solve your problem with confirmation emails is probably to use a distributed transactions with a JMS resource participating in them.

However, as a quick-and-dirty solution, you may try to create a wrapper around a [`PlatformTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html) which will execute `Runnable`s registered in some `ThreadLocal` storage after successfull commit (and remove it from `ThreadLocal` after rollback). Actually, `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` have exactly this kind of logic with `TransactionSynchronization`s, but it's buried too deep into its implementation details.

Comment: I've gone with the quick-and-dirty solution for now. I've built a ThreadLocal based mechanism that associates a queue of Runnable objects with a TransactionStatus object. On commit() or rollback() of a TransactionStatus I either execute the Runnable objects or discard them. It works quite nicely.

Comment: I wouldn't say that distributed transactions are the right _proper_ solution. Distributed transaction would fail the whole transaction if merely sending the mail has failed. But the desired behavior here is that the mail depends on DB-transaction and the DB-transaction doesn't depend on the mail.

Answer (score 12):

This works for me:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
    new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterCommit() {
            // things to do when commited
        }
        // other methods to override are available too
    });
```

Comment: Nice ! Best answer in relation to the question IMO. This is most similar to SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

Comment: @oliv the problem comes when unit testing this piece of code.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of TransactionSynchronizationManager without needing to hack PlatformTransactionManager.

Note: TransactionAware is a marker interface indicating that a ApplicationListener wants to receive a Event after transaction is committed successfully.

```
public class TransactionAwareApplicationEventMulticaster extends SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster {

    @Override
    public void multicastEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        for (ApplicationListener listener : getApplicationListeners(event)) {
            if ((listener instanceof TransactionAware) && TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()) {
                TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
                    new EventTransactionSynchronization(listener, event));
            }
            else {
                notifyEvent(listener, event);
            }
        }
     }

     void notifyEvent(final ApplicationListener listener, final ApplicationEvent event) {
          Executor executor = getTaskExecutor();
          if (executor != null) {
               executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         listener.onApplicationEvent(event);
                    }
               });
          }
          else {
               listener.onApplicationEvent(event);
          }
     }

    class EventTransactionSynchronization extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter {
        private final ApplicationListener listener;
        private final ApplicationEvent event;

        EventTransactionSynchronization(ApplicationListener listener, ApplicationEvent event) {
            this.listener = listener;
            this.event = event;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(int status) {
            if ((phase == TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS)
                    && (status == TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_COMMITTED)) {
                notifyEvent(listener, event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```